# NSPredicate for checking the same date

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsdate, nspredicate, nsdatecomponents

I want to check to 2 `NSDate`s that they are on the same date (time can be different).
What I have currently is this:

```
- (NSPredicate*) predicateWithDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit ) fromDate:date];
    //create a date with these components
    NSDate *startDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    [components setMonth:0];
    [components setDay:1];
    [components setYear:0];
    NSDate *endDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:startDate options:0];
    return [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((ANY notes.date >= %@) AND (ANY notes.date < %@))",startDate,endDate];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your startDate, endDate calculation looks almost correct, you only forgot the `NSDayCalendarUnit`:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
```

There are various ways to compute the start and end date for the current day,
I prefer the following slightly shorter code:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *startDate;
NSTimeInterval interval;
[calendar rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&startDate interval:&interval forDate:date];
NSDate *endDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval];
```

Your predicate will find all objects that have any note with `date >= startDate`,
and any (possibly different) note with `date < endDate`.

If you want to find objects that have at least one note on the given day, you need a SUBQUERY:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(notes, $n, $n.date >= %@ AND $n.date < %@).@count > 0",
           startDate,endDate];
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer! 
I checked and got an exception "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "SUBQUERY(notes, $n, $n.date >= %@ AND $n.date < $@).count > 0"'"

Comment: @Shmidt: Oops, `count` should be `@count`, fixed in answer.

Comment: I tried updated code two times more and cleaned project, but it still shows the same exception.

Comment: @martin_r I see it's the same meaning as in my code,so I'll go with it.

Comment: @Shmidt: There was another stupid error, `$@` must be `%@` of course. I hope that it is correct now.

Comment: Thank you. I use date '2015-10-16 08:00:00 +0000' to find
'2015-10-16 13:40:03 +0000', but NSPredicate is still nil. Did I miss anything?

Comment: I'll check startDate and endDate.

Comment: Both startDate and endDate have time 20:00, startDate is 15th, and endTime is 16th. Is it possible to set time to 00:00?

Comment: Both startDate and endDate should have time 00:00 **according to your time zone**. But NSLog (or "po" in the debugger) prints the times in GMT, as you can see from the trailing "+0000". - Try "p startDate" in the debugger console, or print the times using a NSDateFormatter.

Comment: @martin_r the date are in between startDate and endDate, but predicate is not working... Can't understand what's wrong...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39370/discussion-between-martin-r-and-shmidt)